# Is it possible to prevent react-modal from unmount when its close?

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

```
import Modal from 'react-modal'
...
<div>
    <button onClick={() => this.setState({showModal : true})/>
    <Modal isOpen=this.state.showModal} className={...}
           onRequestClose={ () =>this.setState({showModal : false})/>
</div
```

I notice that react-modal generate a completely new modal every time its triggered . 
Is it possible to prevent the unmounting process of the modal when its closed ? 
I wish the changes that has been done in the modal will save and perform next time the user open the modal

Comment: can you show how you are using the modal ?

Comment: Changes should depend on state, meaning you should persist that state and once user opens modal again, previous changes should be applied based on persisted state (if exists).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `keepMounted` tag:

```
<Modal keepMounted />
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and seems incomplete. Please complete the answer and make sure it answers the question without requiring additional context.